# Is there a way to make an HTML div act like a body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div act like a body tag. By that, I mean that if I have an image styled like this:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

then it would end up being positioned at the bottom of the div rather than at the bottom of the entire page. Is there any way which I could maybe do this? I cannot prevent the elements inside the div from having absolute positioning easily (it is a preview window for a game engine that I am working on for web based games where users can customize the CSS of elements). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why its sitting at the bottom of the page is because, your current code tells the image to sit *absolutely* to its parent , which in this case, is your main html since none is set.

So set the containing div which holds that image as the parent by setting it `position: relative`. When you do so, now the image will sit *absolutely* to the parent which will be that containing div.

Eg;

```
<div class="img-container">
 <img src="blablabla.jpg">
</div>

.img-container {
 position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add `position: relative` to whatever element is wrapping your img and it will be positioned at the bottom of that element. Reference this [W3Schools lesson](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).